# I am being asked to encode a URL. How do I do this?

Tags: java, php, url, encode

I am being asked to encode a header image parameter into a base url but I am not sure how to do this.  Here is a screenshot of the document they have supplied me: http://postimage.org/image/6hkscqdld/

Basically they have a page that I am suppose to use, but I can add a custom header image to that page by adding a parameter to the URL, however the dynamic header image tag must be encoded. How would I go about encoding it?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/your/url/goes/here';
urlencode($url);
```

The above will take a string and encode it properly for use in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

in php you can just use the function

```
urlencode($string);
```